# Keeping objects selected when changing selection types

Tags: vba, selection, powerpoint

I have a macro that allows people to select ListBox items using either `fmMultiSelectMulti` and `fmMultiSelectExtended`. The two options can be switched at any time using radio buttons. However, if someone selects a group and then changes the selection, the selection is cleared. Is it possible to keep the selection through the changing process?

```
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
   ListBox1.MultiSelect=fmMultiSelectMulti
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
   ListBox1.MultiSelect=fmMultiSelectExtended
End Sub
```

Comment: You could capture the current selection (eg. in an array or collection) and then re-apply it after changing the selection type.

Comment: @TimWilliams That's a good idea but I'm wondering if there happens to be a more "VBA" way. I'm trying to learn more about the language as I do this. If not, that's fine as the array idea shouldn't be hard at all

Answer (score 1):

One slightly more PPT way of doing things:

```
Dim oRng As ShapeRange
Dim x As Long

Set oRng = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

' Select something else as a test:
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select

' Now restore original selection
oRng.Select

' Then at this point you could clear your list box and
For x = 1 To oRng.Count
    ' add the shape's name to the list box
    Debug.Print oRng(x).Name
Next
```

This would have the advantage of automatically restoring the previous selection of shapes. On the other hand, Tim's way of doing it would be more generally useful (ie, you could re-use the same code for any list box situation).